# Validation in onFocusChange

Tags: android

I have multi `EditTexts`.
How can i validate the `EditText` from having "" in the `EditText` and if the `EditText` is "" then i want the user to must enter a number before it goes to edittext2
How can this be done?

```
case R.id.P2Throw1Set2:
    p212r.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p2score.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(p212.getText().toString())));
    p2score.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p212r.getText().toString())));
    break;
case R.id.P2Throw2Set2:
    p222r.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p2score.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(p222.getText().toString())));
    p2score.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p222r.getText().toString())));
    break;
case R.id.P2Throw3Set2:
    p232r.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p2score.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(p232.getText().toString())));
    p2score.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p232r.getText().toString())));
    break;
case R.id.P2Throw4Set2:
    p242r.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p2score.getText().toString()) - Integer.parseInt(p242.getText().toString())));
    p2score.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p242r.getText().toString())));
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to disable all but the first edit text and only enable them when the user has provided satisfactory input.  Then wrap your parseInt() calls in try/catch blocks like so:

```
case R.id.P2Throw2Set2:
    try
    {
        p222r.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p2score.getText().toString()) -
            Integer.parseInt(p222.getText().toString())));
        p2score.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(p222r.getText().toString())));

        // if the previous lines worked, this will work
        p232r.setEnabled(true);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // user entered "" or the value was null
        // in this case, we leave the next edit text disabled
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late answer, but you might take a look onto the [declarative form validation techniques](http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2014/01/baracus-from-scratch-part-6-automatic.html) and [advanced validation](http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2014/10/tutorial-9-writing-custom-validators.html) implemented in the BARACUS framework for Android applications coping with the problems of validation in Android apps. Since the stuff is open source feel free to use source fragments coping with validation if you don't want to use a framework.